# Codename One Overflow menu in a generic Container, not only in a Form

Tags: codenameone

I know that in Codename One there is an overflow menu available in the Toolbar using one or more times the method `addCommandToOverflowMenu`.

Without reinventing the wheel (that means reimplementing the overflow menu from scratch), is there an easy way to add an overflow menu in any other Container, not only in a Form?

My use case is a social app with users posts, in which each post should have an header that will be a BorderLayout, with an OverflowMenu on the right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. And frankly the implementation of the overflow menu in `Toolbar` isn't very good so you're better off. This is however pretty easy to implement properly:

```
Button overflow = new Button();
FontImage.setMaterialIcon(overflow, FontImage.MATERIAL_MORE_VERT);
overflow.addActionListener(e -> {
    Button op1 = new Button("First Option");
    Button op2 = new Button("Second Option");
    Dialog d = new Dialog("", BoxLayout.y());
    d.addAll(op1, op2);
    d.showPopup(overflow);
});
```

Note that you might prefer using an `InteractionDialog` instead of `Dialog` in which case the code should still be similar.